# How to run "sudo su" command in Jenkins Declarative pipeline?

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a strange situation where the shell command "sudo su" is not working as expected in Jenkins Declarative pipeline. Below is my code:

```
 stages {

     stage('Ansible-dynamichost-generation') {



           steps {
                   ansiColor('xterm') {


                                        sh 'chmod -R 777 /home/jenkins-slave/'
                                        sh 'sudo su ansible'


                                        sh '''#!/bin/bash -l 
                                        #Execute commands
                                         echo "$WORKSPACE"
                                         whoami
                                         '''

                                         }
                                 }
                            }

  }
```

This pipeline is being run by a jenkins-slave user. However, I have a shell command in pipeline that is supposed to switch to a user called "ansible". But, when the "whoami" command is executed, it returns with an output of "jenkins-slave" itself. Can anyone help as to what is going wrong here ?

Comment: `sudo -u ansible /bin/bash -c "..."`.

Comment: `su` doesn't "switch" users; it starts a new shell run *as* that user.

Comment: @chepner thanks! Yes, I am using "sudo -u ansible" ahead of the command.

Answer (score 0):

each sh commands are execute in sperate sheel.
 better write one sh and do the operation it will work

Comment: How does using multiple "sh" cause the above issue ? Can you please elaborate ? And, I also did try calling all shell commands under one "sh" block and the issue still persists.